# undo moving of a folder in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, undo

There are times when instead of scrolling vertically in file explorer I accidentally move a folder to within another folder. Great! It happens so quick I don't know which folder was moved and this means I just screwed up an application installation.

Is there a way to undo this operation? Or someway to disable moving of folders by default?

Using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

or

<kbd>ALT</kbd> to display menu then `Edit` -> `Undo Move`

Of course this only works if the Move was the last thing you did!

Comment: I  did a control-z but didn't see a visual cue so maybe it worked. Don't know what got moved and so don't know if folder got moved back!

Comment: I'm asking this exact question: How do you know what got moved or undone?  http://superuser.com/questions/347494/how-to-determine-exactly-which-file-actions-will-be-reverted-when-doing-an-undo/347597

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> key usually does an [undo](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-undo-an-accidental-move-or-delete-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/).

Comment: beat you to it :)

Comment: yeah :) good going, +1 there.